# Как создать изображение из его текстового представления?

Tags: python, python-3.x, изображения, lazarus

Если в IDE Lazarus где-либо добавить изображение и сохранить проект, то в файле `.lfm` проекта оно будет сохранено в виде текста. Вот пример:

```
5A000000424D5A00000000000000360000002800000003000000030000000100
200000000000240000006400000064000000000000000000000021FF00FF6E00
FFFF00D8FFFFCC483FFF000000FFFFFF00FFFF0048FF241CEDFFFFFFFFFF
```

Мне нужно создать файл изображения в `.png`, исходя из таких данных. Для начала я пытался извлечь цвета пикселей, чтобы попиксельно создавать изображения. Я смог найти коды цветом в этом тексте, хоть они и оказались перевернутыми. Но даже если у меня получится правильно извлечь все цветовые коды, то я не знаю, как сохранить их в файл. Для решения использую Python 3.4. Думаю, что регулярные выражения помогут в решении. Изображение выше имеет размер `3x3` пикселя, где у каждого пикселя свой цвет, и содержит следующие цвета (hex):

```
4800FF, ED1C24, FFFFFF,
3F48CC, 000000, 00FFFF,
00FF21, FF006E, FFD800
```

Comment: Цвета в какой цветовой модели заданы?

Comment: Hex. Там же написано.

Comment: 8-битный RGB, записанный в 6 байтах? Hex это не цветовая модель

Comment: По крайней мере, такие 6 байт встречаются в строке. А насчёт цветовой модели в тексте - не знаю.

Comment: Так они в строке 8битные 21FF00FF 6E00FFFF 00D8FFFF CC483FFF 000000FF FFFF00FF FF0048FF 241CEDFF FFFFFFFF

Comment: Разве последние 2 бита - не прозрачность? Или как это работает?